# Separating code from layout in template

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have an app built around an MVC pattern.
The view is php but mostly html with minimal php code embedded, stuff like this -

```
Welcome <?php echo $USERNAME ?>
```

and

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($USERS as $row) : ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row->name ?><td><?php echo $row->address ?></tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I only want display layout logic in this file,and I want to keep it simple!

This is mostly working really weel for me however I'm struggling a bit certain aspects.
For example look at the table in the code above and imagine that each column (name, and address) has a title
    NameAddress

Now imagine I want to make the columns sortable. So I make it something like -

```
<tr><th><a href="?sort=name">Name</a><td><a href="?sort=addr">
```

But this isn't good enough. My view needs to look at which column is being sorted by and add an up or down arrow. It needs tochange the link of the currently sorted column to ?sort=name_reverse if that column is already being sorted so that clicking on it sorts it the other way.
It's a bit too complicated to write nice neat code in my template now...

So I can get my controller to create variables containing -

```
<tr><th><?php echo $HEADING[0] ?><th><?php $HEADING[1] ?>
```

etc. BUT this means that my controller is now generating actual HTML which is really the responsibility of the page template. It removes the ability of the template to format page in some different ways... And just feels wrong.

But how can I best deal with this, where I feel I need my page controller to be generating variables containing HTML...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the code to create the table into a ViewHelper. Configure the method call from the template. Have the ViewHelper render the actual table with all required settings. Your main template should then contain only a line like this:

```
<?php echo table($data, $sortOptions, $otherConfig) ?>
```

Basically, any logic required to build that table will be contained within the ViewHelper which is why you might want to make it a class. The complete implementation will vary depending on your needs.

If you dont want to put all the logic into one large Table Helper, consider making helper functions for any parts of the table. For instance, something like

```
<th><?php echo sortLink('Name', $current); ?></th>
```

This way, the sortLink helper would decide whether and how to create and insert any sort links, so you dont have to have that logic or any conditionals in the main template.

Comment: I like this.
Things like sortlink would allow "designers" to transform the data without making them write complex code. And the original data is still there so it doesn't force one particular style unlike providing HTML in variables

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question, which is very uncommon for this site.

First of all you HAVE to accept the fact that any real life template will never be simple.
That's it. It's called presentation **logic** and it follows the complexity of the  presentation itself.

So, just make it the same way as before -- by using the same loop and conditional operator and -- possibly -- some home-brewed helper functions, which will spoil template purity but greatly helps.

In fact, you have almost nailed it. you can use predefined variables, however they should contain no HTML but just values to be displayed.

```
<tr>
 <th>
  <a href="<?=$links['name']['url']?>">
   Name
   <?if($links['name']['dir']=='asc'):?><img src="arrow.gif"><?endif?>
   <?if($links['name']['dir']=='desc'):?><img src="reverse_arrow.gif"><?endif?>
  </a>
 <td>
```

it is tempting to make a loop out of this but I would advise against that, because it will lead you to inventing some HTML builder which is another story and not that reliable as pure HTML itself.

The only blame for you: a programmer, asking for the code assistance, should bring **the code**, not wordy blab. An example of the actual HTML would be much better, allowing answerers not to invent it out of the head.

Answer (score 1):

If I may add a suggestion, you can convert all PHP output to DOM/XML and feed it to an XSLT processor where the presentation, however complex, is more consistent, because XSLT and XHTML are both based on XML. You do get presentation separated from content both in terms of physical location and technology used to deliver it.

Comment: Interesting idea but it wouldn't really solve my problem which is to keep any complex code out of the "view" so that people who aren't full time coders can create themes. I respect XSLT but being simple isn't one of it's best aspects.

Comment: this really depends on your definition of simple. if you ever had to dig into someone else's joomla template, for instance, you'd see that mix of php and html makes so little sense you can spend days going through mazes of author's inventive mind. xslt could be simplified by making pre-cooked templates that solve common tasks, while giving coders the freedom to cook their own. anyway, i agree that xslt isn't for entry level coders, but it's in fact easier to maintain than common php/html mix.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Javascript sorting, there is some good ones for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

If that is not possible y0ou might have a look on some template solution like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to handle templateing for you.

Comment: I agree with you about javascript in this case but I was interested in the general answer of code design mostly. I believe smarty would have the same problem - at some point you get tempted to just feed in HTML markup to your template ...